# Generate date for selected comments

Tags: php, mysql

I will try to describe briefly the problem, namely: I have a page where there are about 1000 profiles. Each profile has its own comments with different dates.

What I would like to do is write a code that would take from each profile 3 last comments, but only the ones whose last comment was no later than 2016 and add them + 6 months, and skips those profiles that have comments from 2017.

I made sample code to add those 6 months:

```
UPDATE `sktest`.`wp_comment`
SET `time` = DATE_ADD(`time`, INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
WHERE date(`wp_comment`.`time`) BETWEEN "2015-05-01" AND "2016-06-01"
```

> Unfortunately, I have no idea how to get only those profiles with 3 last comments that have a date before 2017. Does anyone have any suggestions? Ideas?

Comments I keep in the wp_comment table, which looks like this:
[image: wp_comment table]

The column "whom" is ID of the user profile (in `wp_users`).

**EDIT:**
Ok I did this and seems working. I'm getting 3 last comments from all profiles:

```
$infor=$wpdb->get_results('SELECT a.*, count(*) as row_number FROM wp_comment a JOIN wp_comment b ON a.whom = b.whom AND a.id <= b.id GROUP BY a.whom, a.id ORDER BY a.time DESC');

    foreach ($infor as $info_resr) {        
        $id             = $info_resr->id;
        $active         = $info_resr->whom;
        $time       = $info_resr->time;
        $row_num        = $info_resr->row_number;
        }
       if ($row_num>3) {
           continue;
       }
        echo ''.$active.', '.$time.', '.$row_num.' <br>';   
    }
```

Now, how can I skip those profiles that already have comments from 2017?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use date( )  for `wp_comment`.`time`

```
  UPDATE `sktest`.`wp_comment` 
  SET `time` = DATE_ADD(`time`, INTERVAL 6 MONTH) 
  WHERE date(`wp_comment`.`time`)  BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2016-06-01'
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but how to do this only for 3 last comments in each profile?

Comment: for the last 3 you must use  a procedural  approach .. a procedural language server side or a trigger in db .. because is not possible lmite the number of result using group by  for each aggregation key(whom in your case)

Comment: @scaisEdge are you sure about that?

Comment: @Strawberry  .. about what  ? ... explain better  .. your comment please

Comment: What is and isn't possible

Comment: @for what i not is not possible using SQL  only (not PLSQL)  get the first 3 result for each aggegreagation keys grouped  by  .. if you know how  .. then please post the answer so  .. the Op can resolve the question completly .